# Check a div has a particular style using Javascript/ JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am injecting html code into every webpage before `<body> tag` using chrome extension `content_script.js` file with the `before()` method.
 I am adding `margin-top:60px;` to body tag. It is perfectly displaying in header section to some websites but my problem is some other websites header are stick. They are using  `position:fixed;` css to stick the header.I need to know if we can  identify the div contains style `css position:fixed;` using javascript or jQuery.

Comment: Your question is UNCLEAR

Answer (score 1):

For getting the value assigned to a particular CSS entry of an element and compare it:

```
if ($('#yourElement').css('position') == 'fixed')
{
   // true
}
```

Comment: @user3454856 Check it

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
var x = $('div').filter(function () { 
  return this.style.position == 'fixed' 
});
```

now variable `x` contains all divs with style `position:fixed`

get id by this code:-

```
x.each(function(){
  alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is working good. How to add html (Header) strip for every website using Javascript/ Jquery.

Comment: @user3454856 i didn't got you what you mean by every website? if you want to set html to each div you can use `$('.className').html('html string here');`

Comment: How to get div id from var x

Comment: div class contains postion:fixed; css that class is in style.css. How can i get that div id.